# How to convert an HTMLcollection to a vector in clojurescript?

Tags: dom, interop, clojurescript

I'm trying to apply a function to each element that has a certain class name like so:

```
(map #(js/console.log "element is " %) 
         (.getElementsByClassName js/document "some-class"))
```

But I suppose this doesn't work because `getElementsByClassName` returns an `htmlCollection` and not a vector. I tried wrapping `getElementsByClassName` with `js->clj` and `Array.from`, but neither works. How to convert this `htmlCollection` to a vector so that I can apply the function to each element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [array-seq](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/array-seq) function, like this:

```clj
(array-seq (js/document.getElementsByClassName "foo"))
```

It will convert your `HtmlCollection` instance to a ClojureScript sequence.

Comment: For me, wrapping the htmlCollection in array-see returns nil.